# How to go to Reference of Active cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing code so I can easily go to the reference of 2 cells so I can update data easier.
When I hit the "Ctrl[" while recording macro it goes to the reference for the active cell.

How can I make this work for any active cell reference? here is example of the references in the active cells:

```
='[OVG.xlsx]Net'!$AS$33 , 
='1Q20'!AE37
```

Heres what I have so far...

```
Sub Macro()

    ActiveCell.Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="'Net'!R[16]C[12]"
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -12).Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="'1Q20'!R[20]C[10]"

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do here? Are there 2 specific cells you want to target? What is end result of macro

Comment: There are better (more clear) ways to do this, but what exactly do you mean by how do I make it go to any active cell reference? Do you want to go to specific cells each time? And do you want to take any action on those cells in the code? Or just select them?

Comment: The result is the go to references of each cell and show on the 2 workbooks I have open

Comment: No I just want go to the Reference of the active cell no matter what the active cell or reference is

Comment: @atgold18 - First, only one cell will show at a time. Do you want to ensure that sheet and cell is the one that appears each time you activate a workbook?

Comment: @atgold18 - *No I just want go to the Reference of the active cell no matter what the active cell or reference is* - I am sorry, but I don't understand this. Any workbook is going to show the active cell as it was previously shown when the workbook was deactivated. Perhaps you can update your question with a picture of what you want?

Comment: i have both workbooks open so both will show once I go to them right?

Comment: I just want to go to the location of the reference in active cell so the cell is selected and dont need to look for it

Comment: You're trying to replicate the functionality of `Ctrl+[` if I understand correctly?

Comment: yes but for any active cell or reference in cell. the recording feature only records for the cell you select

Comment: [`Range.Precedents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.precedents) might be helpful here, not sure.

Comment: tried that but says "no cells were found"

Comment: @atgold18 - now I think I understand a bit more. the issue you are going to have is that for any given active cell it may or may not have a formula and thus you may or may not be able to go to the cell range in that formula. Furthermore, how would the code know which cell to go to if there were multiple cell references in the formula. Or if the formula had a range of cells? It gets complicated, but I think @bigBen was right with `Range.Precedents` suggestion, so long as there are actual precedents.

Comment: So why does it say no Cells were found when trying Range.precedents ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a totally different way of doing it but it accomplishes what I wanted!

```
Sub Reference()

    str1 = Range(ActiveCell.Address).Formula
    startpos = InStr(str1, "x]") + 2
    endpos = InStr(str1, "'!")
    str2 = Mid(str1, startpos, endpos - startpos)
    str3 = Mid(str1, endpos + 2)


    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
    Sheets(str2).Select
    Range(str3).Offset(0, -28).Activate
    ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -12).Select

    str1b = Range(ActiveCell.Address).Formula
    startposb = InStr(str1b, "='") + 2
    endposb = InStr(str1b, "'!")
    str2b = Mid(str1b, startposb, endposb - startposb)
    str3b = Mid(str1b, endposb + 2)

    Sheets(str2b).Select
    Range(str3b).Select


End Sub
```